# SAS transpose table with several VAR options

Tags: arrays, sas, transpose

I have a table, that looks like:

```
ID     NAME    TYPE        DATE_VALUE    STRING_VALUE      NUMBER_VALUE  
1    revenue report_date    01jan2018
1    revenue    name                     Revenue_12m
1    revenue    code                                           1100
1    revenue    sum                                           6000000
```

I want it to look like:

```
ID     NAME     report_date     name          code       sum
1    revenue     01jan2018    Revenue_12m     1100     6000000
```

My code, that gives wrong result (3 rows):

```
proc transpose data=tab1 out=tab2;
by id name;
var number_value string_value date_value;
id type;
run;
```

Comment: Is it always the case that only one of the three will be non-missing?  Also do you need the output variables to retain the attributes of the original?  Or could they all be converted to character variables?

Comment: I need original attributes, if it possible. Yes, I need 1 date, 1 name, code and sum. Date cannot be in string_value etc.

Comment: You will have trouble with your string variable. You cannot use NAME as both one of your BY variables and also as the target variable name for one of the new variables to create.

Comment: ok, string is more or less optional. It doubles the name.

Comment: In that case remove NAME from the BY list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider conditional aggregation in SQL, assuming your *types* are a handful of items:

```sql
proc sql;
    create table output as
    select ID, NAME,
           MAX(case when TYPE = 'name' then STRING_VALUE else "" end) AS report_name,
           MAX(case when TYPE = 'report_date' then DATE_VALUE else . end) AS report_date format=date9.,
           MAX(case when TYPE = 'code' then NUMBER_VALUE else . end) AS code,
           MAX(case when TYPE = 'sum' then NUMBER_VALUE else . end) AS sum
    from raw
    group ID, NAME;
quit;
```

**Input**

```
data raw;
    infile datalines delimiter=',' DSD; 
    length NAME $ 7 TYPE $ 11 STRING_VALUE $11 NUMBER_VALUE 7;
    input ID NAME $ TYPE $ STRING_VALUE $ NUMBER_VALUE DATE_VALUE date9.;
    format DATE_VALUE DATE9.;
    datalines;
1,revenue,report_date,,.,01jan2018
1,revenue,name,Revenue_12m,.,.
1,revenue,code,,1100,.
1,revenue,sum,,6000000,.
;
```

**Output**

```
ID    NAME   report_name   report_date  code     sum 
 1 revenue   Revenue_12m     01JAN2018  1100 6000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by running PROC TRANSPOSE three times, once for each data type.
You also need to remove the conflict over the variable named `NAME`.

So first let's create your example data.

```
data have;
  input ID $ xNAME $ TYPE :$32. DATE_VALUE :date. STRING_VALUE :$50. NUMBER_VALUE;
  format date_value date9.;
cards;
1 revenue report_date 01jan2018 . .
1 revenue name        . Revenue_12m .
1 revenue code        . . 1100
1 revenue sum         . . 6000000
;
```

Now we can generate three separate datasets.

```
proc transpose data=have out=dates(drop=_name_);
  where not missing(date_value);
  by id xname;
  var date_value;
  id type;
run;
proc transpose data=have out=strings(drop=_name_);
  where not missing(string_value);
  by id xname;
  var string_value;
  id type;
run;
proc transpose data=have out=numbers(drop=_name_);
  where not missing(number_value);
  by id xname;
  var number_value;
  id type;
run;
```

And combine them.

```
data want;
  merge dates strings numbers;
  by id xname;
run;
```

Note that this method will not create columns for values of TYPE that are always missing.  You could change the WHERE statements to instead list the values of TYPE that use that particular source variable instead.  But then you would need to know the list of possible values of TYPE in advance, in which case why not just write a data step to do the transform.  Something like this:

```
data want;
  length id $8 xname $50 report_date 8 name $50 code sum 8 ;
  format report_date date9.;
  do until(last.xname);
    set have ;
    by id xname ;
    select (type);
      when ('report_date')  report_date=date_value;
      when ('name')  name=string_value;
      when ('code')  code=number_value;
      when ('sum')  sum=number_value;
      otherwise put 'WARNING: Unknown type. ' id= xname= type= ;
    end;
  end;
  drop type date_value string_value number_value;
run;
```

If you have metadata about your data you could use that to define the variables and generate the SELECT statement.

Comment: hm, I thought about it, but mb I can do it without triple transposing and merging? mb with arrays or smth like that? I can remove column with strung variable, its optional. Only code, sum and date.

Comment: If you know the values of TYPE then just write the data step to do the transform. Use "wallpaper" code.  That is a series of similar statements.  `if type='code' then code=number_value; if type='name' then ...`

Comment: it doesn't help, it creates practically the same structure of table

Comment: See updated answer with example single data step solution.

Comment: Tom. am I right, that using data set option the table has to be sorted by id and xname? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Data doesn't make any sense if it is not grouped by the id variables.  If it is not actually sorted but only grouped then add the NOTSORTED keyword to the end of the BY statement.